# Maven install to checkout and build

Tags: git, maven, github, github-api

I have a maven project which depends on another remote project on git . I added a

```
<scm>
    <connection>scm:git:git@github.com:MY-Group/my.project.git</connection>
    <url>https://github.com/MY-Group/my.project</url>
</scm>
```

into my current projects pom.xml.

When i do `mvn scm:checkout` the project is downloaded into target/checkout folder.

What I would like  to do is to  override`mvn install` to

1. Checkout this remote project first into target folder
2. Build and install this remote project from target folder
3. Then build the current project

Is this possible? If so how can we achieve this? Any help

Comment: Does the remote project not already exist in Maven central?

Comment: No, these are not in central repository and these are company specific files

Comment: Start using a repository manager and use automatic builds systems like Jenkins will make life easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elaborating on khmarbaise's answer in the comments, the kind of inter-project checkout and build dependency is not what Maven's meant for, but *is* was an automatic build system and Maven repository can do well.

A Maven repository, like [Artifactory](http://www.jfrog.com/home/v_artifactory_opensource_overview) or [Nexus](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/) acts like a private version of Maven Central.

[Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org) is a continuous integration system (hopefully you are running it already).  You can configure Jenkins to poll your SCM server for changes and start a build when it sees a change.  Jenkins will build your artifact with Maven and deploy it to your private repository.  Jenkins can also understand inter-project dependencies and start downstream builds after an upstream project is changed.

Besides this being the "right" way to deal with your collection of Maven projects, it'll also save you time if the projects are of significant size.  Let's say you have some core server code that's quite large, and you're writing an interface that talks to the server.  In your original question, you'd have to check out and compile the server in order to work on your interface code, even though you're not going to modify the server.  Better is to have Jenkins build the server for you.  Now people who work on the server project check out and edit that, and people who depend on the server project get a built artifact from the private repository.

Answer (score 0):

Used apache [archiva](http://archiva.apache.org/index.cgi) and the issue stands resolved